# What is the Faster way to fill vector from float pointer?

Tags: c++

Is there a faster way than what I have below to append a number of floats to a vector, where the source floats come from const float buffers? The example below, which is what I currently have, gets called in a loop to append somewhere between 1-16 floats at a time. At any one time, that function can be called 1000's of times within a loop to fill the `dst` buffer. The `ptr` object may be different each time. This is dealing with 3D geometry.

```
void appendFloats(std::vector<float>& dst, const float* ptr, uint32_t count) {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        dst.push_back(ptr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest linear way is

```
dst.insert(dst.end(), ptr, ptr + count);
```

Even a faster way is using the parallel algorithm or OMP.

Comment: With 1-16 floats being inserted each time, a parallel algorithm will almost certainly be slower. +1.